# State not changing in leaflet map.on("click") function in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm using Leaflet with React (not react-leaflet because there seems to be a lot more documentation for standard leaflet), and I want to add functionality in which a user can place Markers on the map.

I've gotten this to work, but the problem is that I want to be able to prevent a user from placing more than one marker at a time. I thought this could be solved by using state for a **count** variable, and incrementing this when a user places a Marker. Then, I can only allow a marker to be placed when **count** == 0 (or if I want the maximum number of pins to be higher I can raise this value).

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import L from 'leaflet'
import '../Stylesheets/Map.css'
import propertyMap from '../images/262.png'


export default function Map() {
    const [map, setMap] = useState()
    const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(true)
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

    // Place Marker on Map
    function placeMarker(e) {
        console.log(count)
        setCount(count + 1)
        var latlng = e.latlng
        console.log(latlng)
        L.marker(latlng).addTo(map)
    }

    // Create map only on initial load
    useEffect(() => {
        var map = L.map('map', { crs: L.CRS.Simple, dragging: false, doubleClickZoom: false, touchZoom: false, scrollWheelZoom: false, boxZoom: false, keyboard: false, zoomControl: false })
        setMap(map)
        var bounds = [[0, 0], [638, 906]]
        var image = L.imageOverlay(propertyMap, bounds).addTo(map)
        map.fitBounds(bounds)
    }, [])


    useEffect(() => {
        if (map) {
            console.log("here")
            map.on('click', placeMarker)
        }
    }, [map])





    return (
        <div id="mapDiv">
            <div id="map"></div>
            <h2>{count}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Unfortunately, the program is behaving very differently than I thought it would based on my understanding. When I **console.log()** **count ** within the **placeMarker()** function, it's always 0. To my understanding, state doesn't update immediately so if you print it within the same function call this makes sense. But when I repeatedly place pins (calling the function repeatedly), the state is still 0.

What's even more bizarre is that I included a  element to display the value of **count**. Upon the first click, it updates **count** to 1. But after this, it stays at 1 no matter how many times I click.

Clearly I'm missing something in my understanding of React and how state works. However, I've poked around every thread I could find and I can't figure out what I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Code is below.